# Tabulator character (\t) not printing with Roboto font in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, roboto

I have a solution using jsPDF where I generate a document dynamically based on user inputs. I have encounter that if the text to print contains the character `\t` everything that go after doesn't print in the PDF document.

Currently the PDF is using the font Roboto, in my tests I have found that without adding the Roboto font and use Helveltica for instance it prints ok by putting space between the words that contains `\t` between them, which I want but with the Roboto font.

I have tried as well to re-load a newer version from Google fonts, but not luck.

The following code should reproduce my problem (previously loaded the Roboto font):

```
var customText = '<p>This\tis\ta\ttest\tusing\ttab</p><p>This is a test using spaces</p>';
doc.setFont('roboto','normal');
doc.text(customText, 1, 10);
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output (with Roboto font, this one is the one by default):

[image]

Why might this happening with a custom font?